# No form values being emailed via PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to get the values from a html form mailed to a email address with php. But when I try to email the form, its sends but no values come in the email? Php is not my area really and I would appeciate some help:  My code so far is:

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="send_mail.php" method="post">


<br />
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >
    provider name *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="providername" type="text" name="providername" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>



<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >
    Address Line 1 *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="address1" name="address1" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >
    Address Line 2 *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="address2" name="address2" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    Post Code *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    ID *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >
    Primary contact *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="primarycontact" name="primarycontact" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >
    Job title *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="job" name="job" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    Name contact email *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >
    Name contact phone number *
  </label>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="contact2" name="contact2" type="number" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

THE PHP:

```
<?php

$webmaster_email = "my_email@yahoo.com";


$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";


$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$providername = $_REQUEST['providername'] ;
$address1 = $_REQUEST['address1'] ;
$address2 = $_REQUEST['address2'] ;
$postcode = $_REQUEST['potscode'] ;
$nctlid = $_REQUEST['nctlid'] ;
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'] ;
$job = $_REQUEST['job'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$contact2 = $_REQUEST['contact2'] ;



function isInjected($str) {
$injections = array('(\n+)',
'(\r+)',
'(\t+)',
'(%0A+)',
'(%0D+)',
'(%08+)',
'(%09+)'
);
$inject = join('|', $injections);
$inject = "/$inject/i";
if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}


if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}


elseif (empty($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}


elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}


else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
$email_address, $providername, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You sending from localhost?

Comment: No this from a server

Answer (score 0):

Your mail-function at the bottom is somewhat strangely parameterized. Have a look at

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

and use the parameters as suggested there. In particular, the third parameter seems to be wrong, as it should be the message of your mail, and not a mail_address.

Also, if you want to get the value of a variable in php, you can just call it. So change `"$webmaster_email"`to `$webmaster_email`. The quotes will make it appear as a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

From your php script, **$_REQUEST['email_address']** does not seem to exist at any point either from your html form or from your url query paramaters.

Make sure you are posting the value of **email_address** either from your html form or another source.

Comment: <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name contact email *</label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="email_address" name="email_address" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>